Binary size bloats 20x if moved from src/main.rs to examples/
I'm making a library for Arduino Uno in Rust from scratch. Currently, there's a basic Serial.write print example in the src/main.rs, which on compilation is around 500 bytes (cargo b --release).
$ avr-size target/atmega328p/release/rustymetal.elf # that's the name of bin
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
    488      24       1     513     201 target/atmega328p/release/rustymetal.elf
#                           ^^^ this number is the total size

Which I'd like to port to examples/serial-print.rs, so that I could in future add more examples in different files rather in a single main.rs.
BUT, the same example merely copy-pasted into examples/serial_print.rs directory and compiling via cargo b --example serial-print --release blows up the size immensely, to nearly 10000 bytes!
$ avr-size target/atmega328p/release/examples/serial-print.elf
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   7972    2922       1   10895    2a8f target/atmega328p/release/examples/serial-print.elf

I checked out the cargo bloat output for both, and it was pretty evident there's some kind of dead-code elimination that's NOT happening for the example version (LTO is on for both though):
Here's the output for src/main.rs:
$ cargo bloat --release # this generates the output for bin
    Analyzing target/atmega328p/release/rustymetal.elf

File  .text Size     Crate Name
3.6%  61.9% 302B [Unknown] main
0.2%   2.9%  14B smolduino __vector_22
0.0%   0.8%   4B      core core::result::unwrap_failed
0.0%   0.4%   2B      core core::panicking::panic_fmt
5.7% 100.0% 488B           .text section size, the file size is 8.3KiB

Warning: it seems like the `.text` section is nearly empty. Try removing `strip = true` from Cargo.toml

And here's the output for examples/serial-print.rs(!):
$ cargo bloat --example serial-print --release
    Analyzing target/atmega328p/release/examples/serial-print.elf

 File  .text   Size      Crate Name
 6.7%  21.2% 1.7KiB       core core::char::methods::<impl char>::escape_debug_ext
 3.1%   9.7%   772B       core <core::fmt::builders::PadAdapter as core::fmt::Write>::write_str
 2.6%   8.2%   650B      core2 <&T as core::fmt::Debug>::fmt
 2.5%   8.0%   634B       core core::fmt::write
 2.0%   6.4%   510B       core core::escape::EscapeIterInner<_>::unicode
 1.7%   5.5%   436B       core core::fmt::builders::DebugStruct::field_with
 1.5%   4.8%   384B       core core::fmt::builders::DebugTuple::field_with
 1.4%   4.4%   354B       core <core::str::iter::Chars as core::iter::traits::iterator::Iterator>::next
 1.3%   4.2%   332B      core2 <core2::io::error::Error as core::fmt::Debug>::fmt
 1.3%   4.1%   330B  [Unknown] main
 1.1%   3.5%   278B       core core::unicode::printable::check
 1.0%   3.1%   248B       core core::str::slice_error_fail_rt
 0.7%   2.1%   164B smolduino? <smolduino::error::Error as core::fmt::Debug>::fmt
 0.6%   1.9%   152B       core core::fmt::builders::DebugTuple::finish
 0.6%   1.7%   138B       core <core::fmt::builders::PadAdapter as core::fmt::Write>::write_char
 0.4%   1.1%    90B       core core::str::<impl str>::floor_char_boundary
 0.3%   1.1%    86B       core core::str::traits::<impl core::ops::index::Index<I> for str>::index
 0.3%   1.0%    82B       core <core::char::EscapeDebug as core::fmt::Display>::fmt
 0.2%   0.8%    60B       core core::fmt::Arguments::as_statically_known_str
 0.2%   0.7%    58B       core core::fmt::Write::write_fmt
 1.4%   4.5%   356B            And 18 smaller methods. Use -n N to show more.
31.8% 100.0% 7.8KiB            .text section size, the file size is 24.5KiB

For completeness' sake, here's Cargo.toml, src/main.rs and examples/serial-print.rs:
Cargo.toml:
[package]
name = "smolduino"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
name = "smolduino"
path = "src/lib.rs"
# I'm just doing this to remove the unnecessary error by Rust-analyzer
# I do not need tests rn, but might have to find an alterative soon when I do..
test = false
bench = false

[[bin]]
name = "rustymetal"
path = "src/main.rs"
# I'm just doing this to remove the unnecessary error by Rust-analyzer
# I do not need tests rn, but might have to find an alterative soon when I do..
test = false
bench = false

[[example]]
name = "serial-print"
path = "examples/serial-print.rs"

[profile.dev]
codegen-units = 1
panic = "abort"
opt-level = "z"
lto = true
# strip = true

[profile.release]
codegen-units = 1
panic = "abort"
opt-level = "z"
lto = true
strip = true

[dependencies]
avrd = { version = "1.0.0" }
core2 = { version = "0.4.0", default-features = false, features = ["nightly"] }
paste = "1.0.15"


src/main.rs:
#![no_std]
#![no_main]
#![feature(asm_experimental_arch)]
#![feature(abi_avr_interrupt)]

pub mod error;
pub mod io;
pub mod sync;
pub mod sys;
pub mod timing;
pub mod utils;

use core::{panic::PanicInfo, time::Duration};
use core2::io::Write;
use io::serial::Serial;
use sys::interrupt;
use timing::delay;

#[panic_handler]
fn panic(_info: &PanicInfo) -> ! {
    loop {}
}

#[no_mangle]
extern "C" fn main() -> ! {
    unsafe {
        interrupt::enable_intr();
    }

    let mut serial = Serial::with_baud_rate(9600).unwrap();
    loop {
        // Rust flex, UTF-8 text now works on Arduino!
        serial.write_all("नमस्ते ॐ\n".as_bytes()).unwrap();
        delay::delay(Duration::from_secs(5));
    }
}

examples/serial-print.rs (as you can see it's literal copy-paste, with import statements adjusted):
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

use core::{panic::PanicInfo, time::Duration};
use core2::io::Write;
use smolduino::io::serial::Serial;
use smolduino::sys::interrupt;
use smolduino::timing::delay;

#[panic_handler]
fn panic(_info: &PanicInfo) -> ! {
    loop {}
}

#[no_mangle]
extern "C" fn main() -> ! {
    unsafe {
        interrupt::enable_intr();
    }

    let mut serial = Serial::with_baud_rate(9600).unwrap();
    loop {
        // Rust flex, UTF-8 text now works on Arduino!
        serial.write_all("नमस्ते ॐ\n".as_bytes()).unwrap();
        delay::delay(Duration::from_secs(5));
    }
}

Here's the target .json atmega328p.json:
{
    "arch": "avr",
    "atomic-cas": false,
    "cpu": "atmega328p",
    "data-layout": "e-P1-p:16:8-i8:8-i16:8-i32:8-i64:8-f32:8-f64:8-n8-a:8",
    "eh-frame-header": false,
    "exe-suffix": ".elf",
    "late-link-args": {
        "gcc": [
            "-lgcc"
        ]
    },
    "linker": "avr-gcc",
    "llvm-target": "avr-unknown-unknown",
    "max-atomic-width": 8,
    "no-default-libraries": false,
    "pre-link-args": {
        "gcc": [
            "-mmcu=atmega328p"
        ]
    },
    "relocation-model": "static",
    "target-c-int-width": "16",
    "target-pointer-width": "16"
}

It is worth mentioning, that for AVR targets, you need to be on nightly.
EDIT: As requested, here's the memory map (by avr-ld) for the binary output,
and here's the memory map (by avr-ld) for the example output.
EDIT 2:  Hmm.. it doesn't seem to be an issue with avr-ld. All the same arguments are being passed to avr-ld in both cases, the issue is originating from Rust/LLVM side I guess.

Are you sute this is using GCC and not Clang/LLVM?

This uses avr-gcc for linking, but the code compilation is by LLVM only.

In that case, avr-gcc is just used as a front-end for avr-ld.  Any code generation is up to clang/llvm.

avr-ld is not a valid tag, and it would be nice to get opinion of someone that knows avr-ld details, so avr-gcc tag should stay.

Maybe you can show which commands are issued in either case and the map file from avr-ld as of -Map <file>.

@emacsdrivesmenuts I've added the map files as you've requested.

So you have to nvestigate those map files, and which additional objects are being pulled in.  Or which objects / symbols increased in size.  And then find out why they are being pulled in. Optimization? Debug build+pptions? Missing --gc-sections? etc.

Hmm.. it doesn't seem to be an issue with avr-ld. All the same arguments are being passed to avr-ld in both cases, the issue is originating from Rust/LLVM side I guess.

Even when avr-ld were passed different arguments it wouldn't be an avr-ld issue, but an issue of the entity that is composing the arguments.  And even when arguments are the same (like same object / lib.a names) their content can be quite different depending on how they have been built.
